# Fetch Oracle procedure metadata with Java when multiple procedure signatures

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, metadata

We have an Oracle DB with multiple signatures of a procedure. They each take 6 parameters, but in each variation of the signature the last parameter is a different type.

For example in one variation the last parameter is a clob, in another it's a varchar.

Before we execute the procedure we look up the columns of the procedure

```
rs = conn.getMetaData().getProcedureColumns(packageName, schema, procedureName, "%");
```

This call always returns the columns of just one representation of the procedure. This is problematic because we use the columns from that response to eventually load our parameters to the callable statement before we execute. We do this so we can get the parameter scope (Input, return, etc). If the metadata fetch pulled the variation where the last parameter is a string but we're actually trying to execute the one with a clob then it errors since it's trying to execute the wrong variation of the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not averse to using the oracle data dictionary, you can get all the procedure/column metadata like this:

```
select * from all_arguments
where user = '<your schema>' 
and package_name = '<you rpackage>'
and object_name = '<your procedure>'
order by subprogram_id, position
```